# to solve or to solving

Tags: word-usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

I now look forward to applying the analytical, problem-solving nature I have cultivated since elementary school **to solve** the major problems faced by society.

Does this need to be replaced by **to solving**

Comment: Deletion of extraneous elements yields: _"I look forward to applying the nature I have cultivated to **solving** the problems."_ The infinitive is incorrect here, and the gerund is better; but best would be _the solution of,_ thus: _"I look forward to applying the nature I have cultivated to **the solution of** the problems."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant - This looks to me like a statement from a résumé. If so, the adjectives _analytical_ and _problem-solving_ might not be “extraneous” – not if that’s what the company is looking for in the position.

Comment: To be clear, by _extraneous_ I mean _not necessary to a grammatical analysis._ Sometimes it is easier to parse a long sentence if we reduce it to its core elements. I thought this might be obvious.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - It’s obvious now. Thanks for clarifying. :-)

Comment: By the way, _apply_ is not perhaps the best verb, since a transitive is called for here, and the intransitive _apply (to)_ causes confusion with the marker of the infinitive _to solve._ A better verb here might be _employ,_ which takes an infinitive: _"I now look forward to **employing** the analytical, problem-solving nature I have cultivated since elementary school to solve the major problems faced by society."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Can you explain how big a mistake it is? Would writing "to solve" as opposed to "solving" in a CV put us in a disadvantageous position? Would an average native speaker be aware of the error?

Comment: Don't worry. It's a very minor point, and hardly a soul would notice. **But** the sentence would be better, and would "read" better (to me, at least) either with _to the solution of the problems_ (which provides a NP) or with _employing_ in place of _applying._ I think the one with _employing_ is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original sentence is correct.

> to applying *something* to solve *something*
>
> I now look forward ***to applying*** the analytical, problem-solving nature I have cultivated since elementary school ***to solve*** the major problems faced by society.

Alternatively, you might say

> to use *something* for *something*
>
> I now look forward ***to using*** the analytical, problem-solving nature I have cultivated since elementary school ***for solving*** the major problems faced by society

or possibly you want

> to apply *something* to *something*
>
> I now look forward ***to applying*** the analytical, problem-solving nature I have cultivated since elementary school ***to*** the major problems faced by society.

"solving" the ills of society is implicit in the last sentence.

> to applying *something* to solving *something*

is awkward in its expression.

Comment: The transitive _apply_ requires a NP as an indirect object here. It can be headed by the gerund _solving_ or _the solution_ (for instance), but not by the infinitive _to solve._